# Time reference with present continuous

Tags: tense, phrase-usage, present-continuous

I have a small doubt: I was doing an exercise where a statement is given which you have to reformulate using a given word.

The statement given:

> The company is selling their products at the trade fair.

The new statement (sale) "The company___________at the trade fair."

**Solution:** "The company's **products will be on sale** at the trade fair."

I didn't understand. Shouldn't it be "The company's products are on sale at the trade fair", since the first statement is in present continuous?

Comment: You need either an extra word in your suggestion: _The company's products are **to** be on sale at the trade fair_, or an omitted word: _The company's products are on sale at the trade fair_. You don't want to say "are be". That all said, I like the published solution best of all: _The company's products will be on sale at the trade fair_. That's how I'd write it.

Comment: @J.R, thanks for replying, I made a mistake, I meant "The company's products are on sale at the trade fair"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, dear. This question cannot have ***a*** right answer.

To begin with, the question (as happens all too frequently in these exercises) has a grammatical ambiguity: Simple present and present continuous forms in English may have either present or future reference, so the 'base sentence' in the question thus supports two different contexts:

> The company is selling their products at the trade fair *right now*.
>   The company is selling their products at the trade fair *next week*.

Consequently, even restricting ourselves to simple present and will-future of the *be on sale* expression, both of these answers are entirely justifiable:

> The company's products are on sale at the trade fair.
>   The company's products will be on sale at the trade fair.

Still restricting ourselves to the *be on sale*, there are more ways of expressing futurity.

> The company's products are to be on sale ...
>   The company's products are going to be on sale ...

But there are also many other possible ways of expressing the proposition using *sale*. Let's start with expressions using *on sale*; unlike the 'right' answers, these all maintain the company's syntactic role as Agent:

> The company has/will have/is going to have/is to have its products on sale ...
>   The company is exhibiting/will exhibit/is going to exhibit/is to exhibit its products on sale ...
>   The company intends to have its products on sale ...
>   The company has put/will put/is going to put/is to put its products on sale ...

And then let's take US usage into account. Around here *on sale* means *at a reduced price*; we say ***for*** sale. So you've got to match all the sentences above with versions using *for* instead of *on*.

And then there are expressions which don't use a preposition, such as

> The company is holding/will hold/is going to hold/is to hold a sale of its products ...
>   The company's sale of its products is taking/will take/is going to take/is to take place at ...
>   The company is pushing/will push/is going to push/is to push sale of its products  ...

You get the idea. There are more ways than one of selling product.

Comment: Thanks you sir, good answer indeed, I got the point now ;)

Comment: @dreamcrash I guess I went a little overboard; but those guys who make up exercises - ***and formal tests***, which people's educational and economic lives depend on - without thinking about these things really really vex me.

Comment: @dreamcrash Note, by the way, that you are right: the answer you suggested is in fact entirely acceptable and the best (because simplest) of the present-tense versions.

Comment: Yep, me either. The teacher explanation was that the statement context implies future, "present continuous for future arrangements or plans"

Comment: Well, it **can** imply that, but it doesn't **have to** imply that. Absent explicit futurive context, present reference is the default reading.

Comment: Yep, I still had my doubts after the teacher explanation, thanks again, unfortunately I can only give one up-vote in this question :/.

Comment: @StoneyB: I like it when you get vexed. Every once in a while, your vexation spurs some damned good answers. :^)

Comment: @dreamcrash  After you pass the course, send the teacher here. We'll straighten him out.

Comment: @dreamcrash This question looks like it was taken from a First certificate, "Use of English" exam paper. I have a few of these exam practice books at home and I can assure you if there is more than one answer acceptable, it is listed in the key section. I suspect your teacher may have checked with the first given answer, somehow ignoring the others.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hi, it was from a first certificate book, probably they use on the book examples from exames.

Comment: @dreamcrash I thought so... however, in the test there is a limit to the number of words available. You must use between two and five words, consequently any answers containing "going to" will not fit. That leaves us with: 1) "The company's products **are on sale** at the trade fair"; 2) "The company **has its products on sale** at the trade fair" and 3) "The company's products **will be on sale** at the trade fair." If I manage to find the original question, I'll post back.